# Scaffold Controller Laravel 5.2 Artisan

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am running following command:

```
php artisan make:controller UserController
```

This is successfully creating Controller but I want to scaffold it with all the basic methods. How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this one

`php artisan make:controller UserController --resource`

shorthand

`php artisan make:controller UserController -r`

---

For Laravel 5.4:

Additional option has been added.

`php artisan make:controller UserController -m=[MODEL_NAME]`

this will make controller with all the resource method and corresponding model

Answer (score 2):

```
php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource --model=Photo
```